# Understanding the difference in a jquery on/off function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been coding up a page and come across something i do not understand.

the goal was to disable the context menu when a button was pressed and enable it again later.

the first example disables the contextmenu but cant enable it again after.

**Note:** the 'off' command is obviously not run right after the 'on' command, I have just pulled the relevant code out for readers convenience.

Can someone please explain to me why this doesnt work:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){return false;});
$(document).off("contextmenu",function(e){return false;});
```

yet this does:

```
function returnFalse(e) {        
    return false;
}
$(document).on("contextmenu",returnFalse);
$(document).off("contextmenu",returnFalse);
```

Comment: I think in your case just need to do `$(document).off("contextmenu")`.

Comment: Can you select an answer so this question is not considered unanswered? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that does not work is because you are saying "on contextmenu, run this anonymous function". Then you are saying "off contextmenu, dont do this new anonymous function"

Anytime you are writing an anonymous function, it is essentially a new function so you can't reference it later.

You have to save off your function for later use, so jQuery knows which function to actually remove.

Answer (score 1):

Because `off` removes a function that is actually attached as a handler to the element. In your first example, you are trying to remove a facsimile anonymous function which has never been attached as a handler.